# Sharing VBOs across multiple mesh objects

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a very small game engine that uses OpenGL ES 2.0.  I'm having a bit of a design issue with integrating VBOs into my Mesh Class.

The problem is that I don't want to instantiate a new VBO for each mesh, and I want the VBO size to be determined by the number of meshes I load into it (not just a fixed size of 2MB or something).

Since there's no realloc function for VBOs, I need to batch load all my vertex data at once.  This is ok, since I only have 4 or 5 small meshes.  So I created a MeshList class.

I call MeshList.AddMesh(Mesh mesh) and it aggregates the vertex/index data of the mesh object and returns the offsets into the array of vertex data/index data back to the mesh that was added.  This way the mesh knows where it is in the VBO (but not which VBO it's in).

However, none of the MeshList data is uploaded into a VBO until I call MeshList.BindToVBO().  But now, none of my meshes know which VBO they're in.  So I was thinking of creating an array of pointers in MeshList that point to integer member variables in each Mesh class that would hold the VBO Handle.  This way, when BindToVBO() is called, it iterates over the pointer array and updates the VBO Handles in the mesh objects.

I figured, this way it gives me the flexibility of having different mesh objects in different VBOs or all in one VBO.  The only concern I have is whether or not this is a good design.

It's not clear to someone glancing at the code that MeshList.BindToVBO() is updating a whole bunch of mesh objects.  I mean, MeshList does interact with all of the Mesh objects prior to the BindToVBO() call, but there's nothing explicitly saying that by passing a Mesh object to MeshList.AddMesh(), it's essentially subscribing it's VBOHandle members to updates at some point in the future.

I've tried to make this as clear as I can.  Let me know if something needs clarification.

Comment: One consequence arising with this approach that you bind the lifetimes of the mesh data together. What if you want to replace one mesh with another? Either you upload the complete mesh data on changes, or you fragment the VBO data buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly to me sounds like a lot of trouble for a dubious payoff. Do you have a reason to believe that putting multiple meshes in the same buffer is going to make a noticeable in your performance?

It sounds like premature optimization to me.

Sure, if you have a particle system with 50,000 particles I could see wanting that to be in a shared buffer, but in general I don't know if there's a benefit to storing two arbitrary meshes in the same buffer. It just sounds like a huge potential for bugs and headaches.

Comment: I agree that there is definitely a cost/benefit analysis to be done to determine if it's worth the effort of putting meshes together in one VBO vs binding VBOs for each draw call.  But I'm trying to design my program so I can decide which meshes go in which VBO instead of always having a separate VBO for each mesh, or always all meshes in one VBO.

Comment: @Legion so what is the question here exactly?

Comment: Basically I'm wondering if it's considered bad design to have a class A that contains a list of pointers to member variables in class B. Class A can use those pointers to update the values of Class B's members.  My concern is that it can lead to non obvious changes in Class B's state.   So ClassA.doSomething() affects Class B.